# Custom terms in custom category taxonomy

Tags: customization, taxonomy, terms

I have a Custom Post Type called 'directory'. I have a custom category taxonomy assigned to the post type called 'directories'. This custom taxonomy has several custom terms (e.g. one is 'art supplies' (slug is 'art-supplies')).

I can get all my custom taxonomy terms to list out to the screen as links but I can't find a way that when one of the custom term links is clicked to show all posts assigned to that term.

Is there a way to do this and if so, how would I go about it?

Thanks for your help.

Kev

Comment: Can you share with us the code you have used so far?

Comment: What happens when you click on the link? Also, sharing your code here will help people understand the scenario.